# How to execute AWS emr and redshift scripts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, emr

I have files in `S3 folder` where I have to use `PiG scripts` from `EMR` to do transformation and then load back to s3.

After that I have created tables in `redshift` which are loaded from S3.

Currently, I have used SQL work bench to load files from s3 and also I have executed pig script from AWS GUI window.

I would like to know how can I call the pig scripts from unix shell?
How can I execute the redshift scripts apart from sqlworkbench?
How can I run them sequentially?

Do I need to have EC2 Linux setup to connect to EMR? 
Note: I have an Windows EC2 instance also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to use EMR launcher code, you can use amazon cli or amazon java SDK to do. Using this you can launch EMR job.

You can use amazon EMR console as well to create cluster. Please select step pig program and give path for your pig script which is S3. 
Specify in path for input location in S3 and output location to s3. Launch the Job.

Once the Job is over it will write output to s3.

Once the job is done upon success for job , launch the script( python, shell or java code) to trigger copy command. This script should connect to your redshift cluster, copy the processed out from S3 to redshift table .

You can connect EMR and redshift from your local machine or you can use EC2 to trigger your EMR launcher and redshift loader scripts.

Comment: Sandesh Let me tell you what I have done so far , then you can guide me. 1.Launched EMR instance. 2.Allready have Ec2 windows. 3. Uploaded files in s3. 4.Created Pig script those tested in cloudera env. 5.As there is firewall set up I have to connect to ec2 windows. 6. I have installed putty and from there I could connect to emr through putty. 7. I want to test sample one line code of pig scripts like load and store command. I should test in the grunt shell opened in putty. Can you please verify the steps and then I can ask my next question.

Comment: put your pig script in s3 as well. if you are using AWS console to create EMR then add setup pig program and run it. You don't need ec2 windows to run the job. You can lunch using your local system as well

Comment: My question is what is the best way to do. Putting ur script in emr cluster or putting them in s3? I am not going to do anything console. I have to do in back end. so my question is whether to wrap the pig scripts in unix and then execute?